# What is the difference between su username and sudo su - username?

Tags: sudo, su

I see both does the same thing and both end me up in the same directory.So is it really the same or there is a difference?

Also doing su and su - makes me root user in both the cases.So how is it even benficial?

Comment: I know my queston is quite the same but I didn't quite understand the difference between all of them and especially when to use what.

Comment: What parts didn't you understand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Description

There are differences between them:

First of all using `su username` you have to provide the password of "username" to be able to switch into its account while with `sudo su - username` for a second with your own password you will become root, then without using any other password you are running the `su - uesrname` to switch into the "username".

The other difference is using `-` with `su` it will switches to  the user while running a login shell, without the `-` you will get a non-login shell.

---

#### Conclusion:

- `su username`:

  - You have to provide the target user's password
  - You will be dropped into a non-login shell (things like `.profile` will not be sourced).
- `sudo su - username`

  - You're using your own password to run the `su` command as root (if you're permitted to)
  - You will get a login shell with the target user access.

---

#### Which one to use:

It's not a good idea to share a single password between users, so it's best to not use `su` at all, instead we can use `sudo`, also there is no need to run something like:

```
sudo su - username
```

we can setup our `/etc/sudoers` file then use something like:

```
sudo -i -u username
```

If you have to use `su`, then always use it like `su -` to make sure everything is sourced as it should be and nothing has been compromised with.